# Is there a Special Hadran for finishing the whole shas?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, siyum

Is there a Special Hadran for finishing the whole shas? or do you just recite the Hadran for the masechta just completed?

Answer (score 3):

In the Artscroll gemara, it has the text of:

> הדרן עלך מסכת נדה (ותלמוד בבלי) והדרך עלן. etc

So, it seems that no.

---

As for siyum shas mishnayot, i speak from experience that there is a special hadran, so perhaps there is for gemara as well, but just not in my sefer.

Comment: If I recall correctly, at the recent Daf Yomi completion, they had a Hadran for all of Sha"s. I may still have the brochure around which may have it in there.

Comment: What about Yerushalmi?

Comment: There is a similar text at the end of masechtot that finish a seder, such as "Hadran alecha masechet middot v'seder kodshim"