# Is there a special hadran on Yerushalmi?

Tags: how-to, siyum, talmud-yerushalmi

Inspired by [DoubleAA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40909/is-there-a-special-hadran-for-finishing-the-whole-shas#comment108709_40915). Is there a special text one should say on finishing a Masechta in Yerushalmi?

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn’t make the same one said on Bavli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most notably by saying

> הדרן על מסכת ברכות **מתלמוד ירושלמי**

As demonstrated at [this siyum](http://www.yerushalmionline.org/audio-shiurim/) (recording #31).

There didn’t seem to be any other changes.

[DoubleAA’s](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40909/is-there-a-special-hadran-for-finishing-the-whole-shas#comment108709_40915) comment was a simple pun demonstrating that when it would be a Siyum HaShas for Yerushalmi, one would say

> הדרן עלך תלמוד ירושלמי

As is evident on the last recording linked above.

Comment: I've never heard הדרן על מסכת ברכות מתלמוד בבלי

Comment: @DoubleAA is that significant?

Comment: It indicates at least one of the two is not strictly necessary